# Map-tool for easily creating Twitter location geo-coordinates?

Tags: twitter, geolocation

Does anybody know of a click-and-point tool for creating the four points in a [Twitter streaming locations](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#locations), ie. `stream.filter(locations=[60, 25, 73, 35])`

I'd love a tool to just click/drag a box on a map, and get the copy/paste ready coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up Google Maps, in the bottom left footer, there is a link to the Maps Labs.

From there, you can enable additional tools for Google Maps.

One of these tools is a Latitude and Longitude Marker which you can drop onto the map at any point.

Answer (score 0):

This is a start: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#polylines_complex_v3

And this is actually what I was looking for: http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm